# Tmux display problems on WSL: panes bleed into each other on newlines

Tags: tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use tmux version 3.1c on my Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2 (WSL2) based Debian 11 container running in Docker (version 20.10.12). I build a new tmux session, but when I attach to it, the right pane bleeds into the left pane on double newlines.
My setup:

```
tmux new-session -d 'vim 123'
tmux split-window -h 'vim abc'
tmux attach-session -d
```

contents of 123:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

contents of abc:

```
a
b

c
d

e
```

When tmux opens, it looks like this:

```
1           |a
2           |b
3           |
c
5           |d
6           |
e
8           |~
~           |~
```

Notice the breaks in the dividing vertical line where abc bleeds into 123. I would like to know how to fix this behavior. I don't know if it's caused by WSL or if its a bug with tmux. I don't think its the terminal emulator because I've tried it on Windows Terminal and cmder with the same results.

In case it helps solve the main problem, there is other strange behavior. If any tmux pane is a shell, typing `clear` will return the shell prompt to the top of the pane but will not clear the pane of text until that text is written over. This is not a problem outside of tmux.

Comment: What's your `$TERM` set to? `tmux 3.1c` in WSL with MS terminal works for me.

Comment: Agree with @Panki - I'm unable to reproduce this, even on a freshly installed Debian 11 under WSL (1.0.3) using Windows Terminal 1.15.2713.0.  Tried with the exact steps and contents in your question.

Comment: @Panki, $TERM is "xterm"

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, I'm using WSL version 2.

Comment: @Woodren Right, there's "WSL1" and "WSL2", but there are now multiple releases of WSL2.  1.0.3 is the latest.  Run `wsl.exe --version` -- If you are using a recent release (one from the last 15 months), then it will tell give you version info.  If you just get the help-text back from that command, then you are on an older release.  Try installing [WSL from the Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage).  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @NotTheDr01ds, I updated my WSL2 to version 1.0.3. Unfortunately, that did not fix the issue.

Comment: @Woodren Right - I really wasn't thinking that it was a version issue, but it's worth it to make sure you are on the latest release.  Still trying to figure out what might cause the difference here.  I tried it with CRLF line endings in `abc`, but couldn't reproduce the issue that way, either.  My `TERM=xterm-256color` when not inside Tmux, and `screen` when inside, just for reference.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, thanks again for your effort here. Last night I corrected the problem without fully understanding how. Previously, I had been running the container runtime on top of Docker desktop 4.5.1, in which I ran the Debian container with the problem. Last night, I ran the same experiment directly in WSL without Docker Desktop and it fixed the issue. I ran the experiment again in docker container in WSL without Docker Desktop and also no issue. Seems like Docker Desktop was somehow the culprit.